# F# removing the first occurrence of an element in a list

Tags: f#

I want to remove the first occurrence of a given element in a list that has possible duplicates.
For example, a list with [1; 6; 1]. I only want to remove 1 once and returns the list [6;1]. My current implementation:

```
let rec remove l x =
        match l with
        | [] -> []
        | h::t when h = x -> t
        | h::t -> h::(remove l h)
```

this works only for lists that the number I am trying to remove is the first element. For a list like [6; 7; 6] if I wanted to remove the number 7 and return [6; 6]. It does not traverse the list and remove 7 with my current implementation. What can I do to traverse the entire list and remove only the first occurrence of an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is in the last line of your code

```
let rec remove l x =
     match l with
     | [] -> []
     | h::t when h = x -> t
     | h::t -> h::(remove l h)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. You want to keep the head `h` and process the tail `t` but the code do not do this, referring to `h` and `l`, instead of `t` and `x`.
2. The type signature of `remove` is correctly inferred to `'a list-> 'a -> 'a list` but the wrong second argument is used in the last match branch. It is using `h` rather than `x` as the element to remove parameter.
3. The first argument is also incorrect, since referring to `l` does not change through each recursion. It needs to refer to the latest tail `t`.

So the last match branch should read:

```
| h::t -> h::(remove t x)
```

Here is the full corrected code;

```
let rec remove l x =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t when h = x -> t
    | h::t -> h::(remove t x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing the same code you did and it seems to work just fine. I reordered the parameters for better piping. I could also work to make this tail-recursive.

```fs
let rec removeFirst elem xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t when elem = h -> t
    | h :: t -> h :: (removeFirst elem t)
```

```
> removeFirst 2 [1;2;2;1];;
val it: int list = [1; 2; 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tail-call optimized version

```ml
let removeFirst elem list =
    let rec loop head tail =
        match tail with
        | [] -> list
        | x :: xs when x = elem -> (List.rev head) @ xs
        | x :: xs -> loop (x::head) xs
    loop [] list

removeFirst 1 [1; 2; 3] |> printfn "%A" // [2; 3]
removeFirst 2 [1; 2; 3] |> printfn "%A" // [1; 3]
removeFirst 3 [1; 2; 3] |> printfn "%A" // [1; 2]
removeFirst 4 [1; 2; 3] |> printfn "%A" // [1; 2; 3]
```

How it works:

We're traversing list keeping visited elements in `head` and unvisited in `tail`. Take first element from `tail` and see if it's equal to elem we're searching for. If element is found, reverse `head` and attach to `tail` without removed element. If element is not found, attach current to `head` and continue. If we've reached end of list and element isn't found, then return `list` without modifications.

Example:

Given list of `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]` and element `3` iterations will look like this:

| head | tail | x | xs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [] | [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] | 1 | [2; 3; 4; 5] |
| [1] | [2; 3; 4; 5] | 2 | [3; 4; 5] |
| [2; 1] | [3; 4; 5] | 3 | [4; 5] |

At last iteration element is found and all that's remains is to build list: reverse of `[2; 1]` is `[1; 2]`, attach to `[4; 5]` and get `[1; 2; 4; 5]`.

Note: `head` is kept in reverse to improve performance of building it from O(n2) to O(n). Combining `head` with `xs` in second branch can be improved from **O**(head.length*2) to **O**(head.length) by avoiding usage of `rev` with `@` and building result list manually